# Plugin JavaScripts Confliction

Tags: plugins

I am having as many errors (java conflicts) as i can have

Since I am using as many plugins as i can.

Any one can have any idea to solve this?

I am using plugin load filter plugin to control this.  But this is not working in all times as i want.

Thanking you

People who have the same issue please share this to get answer quickly.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! It's rather hard to answer your question since you don't mention which plugins are conflicting. In most cases you'll need to work with the plugin authors, or else try different combinations of plugins until you find a combination that meets your functionality needs without causing JS conflicts.

Comment: I want general advice.  Is there anyway?